# Flickr API: API key keeps getting invalid?

Tags: api, rest, restful-authentication, flickr

I’ve a Flickr which I’m using to upload pictures from my phone and all images are public. On my blog I want to retrieve all the images to show and for that I’ve first tried to create an application to get my API key. I’m using the Flickr API **flickr.people.getPublicPhotos**. This API service is said to not require authentication and putting it all together I end up with this call:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=fc94274cd0335f3c171fe22c8490b7d9&user_id=5545356%40N04&extras=description%2Cdate_upload%2Cdate_taken%2Cowner_name%2Coriginal_format%2Ctags%2C+o_dims%2C+views%2C+media%2C+path_alias%2C+url_sq%2C+url_t%2C+url_s%2C+url_q%2C+url_m%2C+url_n%2C+url_z%2C+url_c%2C+url_l%2C+url_o&per_page=40&format=php_serial&api_sig=0c48e2b6b6d9a03521e5ca86a15cf471
```

The problem is that every around 10 hours I fails and returns the error message `a:3:{s:4:"stat";s:4:"fail";s:4:"code";i:100;s:7:"message";s:31:"Invalid API Key (Key not found)";}`

I tried to create the API call when logged in to Flickr and also with not logging in and in both cases I get the error message. It’s like the API key expires or stops working. Have a missed something on Flickr about the API key or what could cause this? It is really frustrating to renew the URL twice at day.

Thank you

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read the docs correctly, the `&api_sig` query string parameter is constructed using an authentication token, one that eventually expires.  Remove that parameter (= do not sign your API request) and I think you'll be OK.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. Do you mean to remove the parameter "api_key=fc94274cd0335f3c171fe22c8490b7d9" from the query string? I tried that and it gives me the error: **Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)**. Or did I misunderstod you?

Comment: No, I mean remove this one: &api_sig=0c48e2b6b6d9a03521e5ca86a15cf471

Comment: Ah I think I found the answer. I removed the API sign as you said in the end. The other issue was that I had used the API explore and for that it seems that it changes. I just used my accounts API key with no API sign and it seems to work. I just cross my fingers that it also works tomorrow :-)

Comment: i am doing as you said but i get this error Invalid API Key (Key not found), i have opened a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704221/invalid-api-key-key-not-found-flickr

Answer (score 1):

Mestika's comment seems correct. I was getting the same problem when using the API explorer. If you use your accounts API, or go in and create a new app, then use the API given for that, then the key doesn't change every few hours.

The url to request a key is:
http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

This is how i solved it:

- **removed** the **auth_token** and the **api_sig** parameters
- **replaced** the **api_key** value with an **app key**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i met this issue before. with new api key, only accept https request.
Let's change your url to: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key.....

I am sure it will be work right know.
thanks